# How to get column width in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in my application.  What I am trying to do is make column titles wrap if they're too large for a single line.  To do this, I must re-size the height of the title.  I can do that.  What I need to do, however, is to  access the column widths after it has been rendered.  I have spent a few hours on it with no luck.  Here is some code I've been using:

```
    calculateDynamicHeaderHeight() {
        const columnDefs = this.columns;
        const gridApi = this.gridOptions.api;
        let maxHeight = 0;
        const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');

        // Apply similar styles as your header cells
        tempDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        tempDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        tempDiv.style.whiteSpace = 'normal';
        tempDiv.style.fontSize = '12px'; // Example font size, adjust as needed
        tempDiv.style.lineHeight = '15px'; // Adjust line height as needed
        tempDiv.style.padding = '0';
        tempDiv.style.margin = '0';
        tempDiv.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';

        // Add any additional styles that your headers have

        document.body.appendChild(tempDiv);

        columnDefs.forEach(colDef => {
            // Set the width of the temporary div to the column width
        
            //  This:
        const colWidth = colDef.width;
        // or this:
            const colWidth = gridApi.getColumnDef(colDef.field).actualWidth;
        
            tempDiv.style.width = `${colWidth}px`;

            // Set the header title as the inner HTML
            tempDiv.innerHTML = colDef.headerName;

            console.log(tempDiv.offsetHeight);
            maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, tempDiv.offsetHeight);
        });
        console.log('');

        document.body.removeChild(tempDiv); // Remove the tempDiv after the loop

        gridApi.setHeaderHeight(maxHeight + 15);
        return maxHeight + 15;
    }
```

This code does set the column title height.  The problem is I can't seem to access the column width.  I tried both of the two line above.  The first return 15 all of the time.  The second is invalid.  I cannot figure out how to get the column widths.  Any help would sure be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Skip all the code.  Just add `wrapHeaderText: true` to your column definition.